# How to make PHP CodeSniffer standard PHPCS validate the ternary operator?

Tags: php, operators, phpcodesniffer

I've been using PHP_CodeSniffer for a few days but I still can't validate some codes. When I use ternary operator, even a very simple like this:

```
$name = (strlen($name) > 0) ? $name : 'nameless';
```

The Code Sniffer says:

> ERROR | Inline IF statements are not allowed

But if I write an invalid code using ternary, like this:

```
$name = strlen($name) > 0? $name: 'nameless';
```

Code Sniffer says "FOUND 4 ERRO(S)...":

> ERROR | The value of a comparison must not be assigned to a variable
>   
> ERROR | Inline shorthand IF statement requires brackets around comparison
>   
> ERROR | Inline IF statements are not allowed
>   
> ERROR | Expected 1 space before "?"; 0 found
>   
> ERROR | Expected 1 space before ":"; 0 found

Why it validate all ternary expressions but, when I fix all, PHPCS says it is invalid? Am I writing it wrong or it simply does not allow ternary at all?

Answer (score 0):

The sniff is failing, not syntax errors.  You have rules defined that you are not following.  You either need to correct your code or remove the rules from the ruleset.

Inline IF statements will be the ternary option you wrote. By your ruleset, you need to write:

```
if (strlen($name) > 0)
{
    $name = $name;
}
else
{
    $name = 'nameless';
}
```

Likely better to remove the sniff from the rules.

In the edited code, the sniffs are complaining that

```
> 0?
```

should be

```
> 0 ?
```

and

```
$name: 'nameless';
```

should be

```
$name : 'nameless';
```